# Are Savon SSL global options required?

Tags: ruby, soap, savon

Integrating with a legacy SOAP service and the HTTP dev environment works fine. Other environments use SSL and it's not clear from the Savon docs if the global SSL options are required or are overrides of Savon or server settings?

```
Savon.client(ssl_cert_file: "lib/client_cert.pem")
Savon.client(ssl_cert_key_file: "lib/client_key.pem")
Savon.client(ssl_ca_cert_file: "lib/ca_cert.pem")
```

We have certs installed on our servers but our Savon implementation does *not* yet set any of the above options.

Currently the SOAP server can be pinged successfully from our environments but Savon calls timeout with `HTTPClient::ConnectTimeoutError: execution expired`.

Comment: Have you tried :ssl_verify_mode => :none?

Comment: @SteffenRoller yes, still gives HTTPClient::ConnectTimeoutError